# Как с помощью атрибутов применить метод ко всем другим методам класса на C#?

Tags: c#

Я хочу реализовать проверку(авторизацию и другие вычисления) для всех методов класса.
То-есть при выполнении каждого метода класса я хочу сперва выполнять определённую проверку, и если она пройдена, то выполнять дальше метод.
Фактически перед каждым методом класса написать выполнение метода проверки.
Можно ли это реализовать с помощью атрибутов или абстрактных классов, или наследования, что б не писать каждый раз выполнение метода проверки, а создать определённую структуру?